# Drawings on books purchased with iBooks

Tags: pdf, books, ibook

Say I buy a book using iBooks (OS X Yosemite on a MacBook Pro). Using iBooks, I can highlight text and add notes. What about drawing shapes? e.g. circles, squares, arrows, etc.

If this is not possible with iBooks itself, is there any way to open a book bought with iBook on a different app with more editing support?

Comment: Nomally paid for books from Apple's iBookstore can only be opened with the iBooks app.  There are a few exceptions where the publisher does not use DRM, like O'Reilly.

Answer (score 1):

If your books are really PDFs, and there are no security restrictions, you could use Adobe/Acrobat Reader with its commenting tools.

Comment: The store where you buy things using iBooks does not carry pdf's.